# chef shell out to hash (separator is new line)

Tags: chef-infra, mixlib-shellout

I just have a recipe with content:

```
echo_example = shell_out("echo "line 1\nline 2")
if echo_example.exitstatus == 0 && echo_example
  node.rm('test')
  node.set['test'] = [echo_example.stdout.chomp]
end
```

Attribute output with knife is:

```
        "test": [
          "line 1\nline 2"
        ]
```

How to get this output using knife below?

```
        "test": [
          "line 1",
          "line 2"
        ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but maybe you can split the output in the recipe, before putting it in the attribute. You can use [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split) for this:

```ruby
node.set['test'] = [echo_example.stdout.chomp.split("\n")]
```

Comment: Thanks, this really separated attributes.